# GCP Identity-Aware Proxy - return 403

Tags: google-cloud-platform, identity-aware-proxy

By default, the GCP IAP (enabled for an API resource) redirects to a google login screen - in case of an unauthenticated request. Instead I need to just return 403.
Please advice if there a simple setting I'm missing? Alternatively please suggest the possible solution.

Comment: Is it for a web access or an API access?

Comment: It is for API access purposes

Comment: IAP returns a 302. If you follow it, you get a 200 with the login page HTML content. AFAIK, you can't customize this. Have a look to Cloud Run if you can!

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere - what do you mean "if you follow it"? Is it maybe possible to overwrite where it redirects to login page and instead show own, which could be a 302?

Comment: No, it's a built-in feature, you can't (or I don't know how).

Comment: You can try adding `HTTP Accept="text/html,*/*"` to your header. See [reference](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/faq#why_am_i_receiving_an_http_401_unauthorized_status_code_instead_of_an_http_302_redirect) for details.

Comment: Edit your question. 1) How are you making your requests (code/REST API, browser, etc)? 2) What HTTP headers are included in your request?

Comment: @JohnHanley - postman or curl. But are you saying it will depend on request headers, whether response will have redirect content or not?

Comment: IAP responds with a 302 Redirect status code when a client is configured to handle redirects. To indicate that your client can handle redirects, ensure that HTTP Accept="text/html,*/*" is in the header of requests.

Comment: so no way to remove redirect irrespective of the client and its headers? I would just like to return 403 if not authorized

Comment: Have you tried adding the HTTP header `Accept: application/json`?